# How to force client side validation of a single element in ASP.NET MVC 3 (jQuery validation)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

How can I force the framework to validate a specific field?

I saw somewhere that I can call `$("form").validate().form()` to force the entire form to validate, but I only want to check just the one field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`element` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/element#element) of the Validator object:

> [`element( element )`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/element#element)           *Returns:* Boolean
>
> Validates a single element, returns true if it is valid, false otherwise.
>
> *Example:*
>
> ```
> $("#myform").validate().element( "#myselect" );
> ```

Comment: Is there an easy way of refreshing the validators attached to that input?

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
$("#myElement").valid();
```